# Make a command start new line in a list if it is not currently at the end of another list

Tags: spacing, macros, lists, line-breaking, enumitem

I am trying to typeset a structured proof
as demonstrated by Leslie Lamport in his paper
[How to Write a 21st Century Proof](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/proof.pdf).
In particular, I am trying to typeset Figure 3 (shown below).

[image]

My code and the output is shown below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% LSP is short for Lamport Structured Proof
\newlist{lsp}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[lsp]{label=\arabic*.}
\newcommand{\lspproof}{{\scshape Proof:\ \ }}
\newcommand{\lspqed}{Q.E.D.}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}
If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ on an interval $I$,
then $f$ is increasing on $I$.
\end{corollary}

\begin{lsp}
    \item It suffices to assume
        \begin{lsp}
        \item $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$
        \item $a < b$
        \end{lsp}
    \lspproof By definition of an increasing function

    \item There is some $x$ in $(a,b)$
    with $\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.\\*
    \lspproof By assumptions 1.1 and 1.2,
    the hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable on $I$,
    and the Mean Value Theorem.

    \item $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.\\*
    \lspproof By the induction hypothesis of the corollary and assumption 1.1.

    \item $\displaystyle \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} > 0$\\*
    \lspproof By 2 and 3.

    \item \lspqed\\*
    \lspproof Assumption 1.2 implies $b - a > 0$,
    so 4 implies $f(b) - f(a) > 0$,
    which implies $f(b) > f(a)$.
    By 1, this proves the corollary
\end{lsp}


\end{document}
```

[image]

While I am quite happy with the result,
I find it a bit irritating that I have to manually tell LaTeX to start a new line using `\\*` before each `\lspproof`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to define `\lspproof` such that it will automatically start a new line when needed?
   Notice that I did not need to insert `\\*` before the "Proof:" in step 1 because the "Proof:" occurs after an enumerate environment.
2. Is there a way to slightly increase the vertical space between the "Proof." from `\lspproof` and the previous line?

Comment: We could just ask Leslie for the code :-)

Comment: I don't know him personally, or rather I know who he is but he doesn't know who I am.
However, I would love it for you or anyone else to ask him. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option that uses a paragraph break rather than a forced line break:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}

% LSP is short for Lamport Structured Proof
\newlist{lsp}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[lsp]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
\newcommand{\lspproof}{\par\nobreak{\scshape Proof:}\quad}
\newcommand{\lspqed}{Q.E.D.}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}
If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ on an interval~$I$, then $f$ is increasing on~$I$.
\end{corollary}

\begin{lsp}
  \item It suffices to assume \label{proof1}
    \begin{lsp}
    \item $a$ and~$b$ are points in~$I$ \label{assump1}
    \item $a < b$ \label{assump2}
    \end{lsp}
  \lspproof By definition of an increasing function.

  \item There is some~$x$ in $(a,b)$ with $ f'(x) = \dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. \label{proof2}
  \lspproof By assumptions~\ref{proof1}.\ref{assump1} and~\ref{proof1}.\ref{assump2}, the hypothesis that~$f$ is differentiable on~$I$,
  and the Mean Value Theorem.

  \item $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$. \label{proof3}
  \lspproof By the induction hypothesis of the corollary and assumption~\ref{proof1}.\ref{assump1}.

  \item $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} > 0$ \label{proof4}
  \lspproof By~\ref{proof2} and~\ref{proof3}.

  \item \lspqed
  \lspproof Assumption~\ref{proof1}.\ref{assump2} implies $b - a > 0$, so~\ref{proof4} implies $f(b) - f(a) > 0$, which implies $f(b) > f(a)$.
  By~\ref{proof1}, this proves the corollary
\end{lsp}


\end{document}
```